# Ant Design Select with option group doesn't show groups with out children

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a problem with the Ant Design select.
It doesn't show the option group having 0 children

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Can you show codebase?

Comment: Antd didn't make it configurable. If there is no children, it doesn't show group label

Comment: If this is the case I would suggest filing a PR. They are good at accepting reasonable new features.